# Python 'Object has no attribute'

Tags: python, object, module

Code gives the following error:

"'module' Object has no attribute 'checkNone'"

Dir setup:

```
+main.py
    Sorcery
    +Check.py
```

main.py

```
from Sorcery import Check
check = Check.checkNone(None);
```

Check.py

```
class Check:
    def checkNone(content):
        if content == None:
            print("None!")
        else:
            print("Check!")
            return content
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You have a module called `Check`, that contains a class also called `Check`. Your code attempts to call `checkNone` from the module, but only the class has such a function. Depending on the rest of your code, possibly the correct fix is to remove the line `class Check:`

Comment: Rename `Check.py` to `check.py` and do `from check import Check`

Comment: Nominally you want `check = Check.Check.checkNone(None)` but that's not going to work for a different reason. `checkNone()` is an instance method where the traditional `self` variable has been named `content` and takes no other parameters. Did you mean that method to be an instance or class method?

Comment: That method mean to be a class method. Can someone give me an easy explanation on that 'self' thing and how do i use it? I also tried the 2 other above comments, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename the `Check.py` to anything you like, e.g.,`jacs.py`. Inside `jacs.py`,  change `Class Check: def checkNone(content):` to `Class Check(object): def checkNone(self, content):`.
Then, in `main.py`, begin with

```
from Sorcery.jacs import Check
output = Check.checkNone(None)
```

Comment: Also, you need to add empty `__init__.py` at the directory of `main.py` and within `Sorcery` to make them [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), see Part 6.4.